# Convert with points separated string to nested complex dict

Tags: python, dictionary

As a java developer I need some tips how to solve this problem in python 2. My skills in python are in a beginning state. But now the question:

We provide a service for devices, which are reporting some technical statistics in a format, which we can not change. The server runs with python.
The main report are coming as dictionaries and we need to save the the json way. The converting from dict to json is not the problem, but converting the flat and with points separated keys need to be converted.

Perhaps an example can show what I want to say. This is the format from the devices, name it source:

```
{
    'Device.DeviceInfo.SoftwareVersion': 'ote-2.2.1',
    'Device.GatewayInfo.ProductClass': 'OEM-TX23',
    'Device.GatewayInfo.SerialNumber': 'A223142D1CC7',

    'Device.Ethernet.Interface.1.MaxBitRate': 1000,

    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.1.AssociatedDevice.1.RxPhyRate': 522,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.1.AssociatedDevice.1.TxPhyRate': 706,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.1.AssociatedDevice.1.Active': 1,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.1.AssociatedDevice.1.MACAddress': 'af:49:79:e4:64:fc',

    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.1.AssociatedDevice.2.RxPhyRate': 544,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.1.AssociatedDevice.2.TxPhyRate': 0,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.1.AssociatedDevice.2.Active': 1,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.1.AssociatedDevice.2.MACAddress': 'af:49:79:e4:64:dd',


    'Device.Ethernet.Interface.2.MaxBitRate': 1000,

    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.2.AssociatedDevice.1.RxPhyRate': 671,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.2.AssociatedDevice.1.TxPhyRate': 607,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.2.AssociatedDevice.1.Active': 1,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.2.AssociatedDevice.1.MACAddress': 'bf:49:79:e4:64:fc',

    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.2.AssociatedDevice.2.RxPhyRate': 340,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.2.AssociatedDevice.2.TxPhyRate': 0,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.2.AssociatedDevice.2.Active': 1,
    'Device.HomePlug.Interface.2.AssociatedDevice.2.MACAddress': 'bf:49:79:e4:64:dd'
}
```

The Integer values within the source represents the index of the interfaces and AssociatedDevices for this interfaces. So the part behind an integer should be a **list of multiple dictionaries**. The integer value **should not be included** within the result.

We need the following nested structure before we can persist it to database, especially mysql docstore. And again, the conversion from nested dict to json is not the problem.

Here is the format we need:

```
{
    'Device': {
        'GatewayInfo': {
            'SerialNumber': 'A223142D1CC7',
            'ProductClass': 'OEM-TX23'
        },
        'DeviceInfo': {
            'SoftwareVersion': 'ote-2.2.1'
        },
        'Ethernet': {
            'Interface': [{
                'MaxBitRate': 1000
            }, {
                'MaxBitRate': 1000
            }]
        },
        'HomePlug': {
            'Interface': [{
                'AssociatedDevice': [{
                    'RxPhyRate': 522,
                    'TxPhyRate': 706,
                    'Active': 1,
                    'MACAddress': 'af:49:79:e4:64:fc',
                }, {
                    'RxPhyRate': 544,
                    'TxPhyRate': 0,
                    'Active': 1,
                    'MACAddress': 'af:49:79:e4:64:dd',
                }]
            }, {
                'AssociatedDevice': [{
                    'RxPhyRate': 671,
                    'TxPhyRate': 607,
                    'Active': 1,
                    'MACAddress': 'bf:49:79:e4:64:fc',
                }, {
                    'RxPhyRate': 340,
                    'TxPhyRate': 0,
                    'Active': 1,
                    'MACAddress': 'bf:49:79:e4:64:dd',
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The first answer is partially correct, except that the parts after the integers should converted to a list containing the rest as dictionary.

Comment: Not much, played with traversing the list and try to understand different data structures in python. But my problem is, python is new for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Just pass the unconverted `dict` to `convert` and it will return the converted `dict`

```
def convert(data):
    to_convert = set()
    new_dict = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        path_stack = []
        k_list = key.split('.')
        temp_dict = new_dict
        for k in k_list[:-1]:
            path_stack.append(k)
            if k.isnumeric():
                to_convert.add(tuple(path_stack))
            if k not in temp_dict:
                temp_dict[k] = {}
            temp_dict = temp_dict[k]
        temp_dict[k_list[-1]] = value

    for path in sorted(to_convert, key=len, reverse=True):
        current_level = new_dict
        for k in path[:-2]:
            current_level = current_level[k]
        if isinstance(current_level[path[-2]], dict):
            new_level = [current_level[path[-2]][i] for i in sorted(current_level[path[-2]].keys())]
        else:
            new_level = current_level[path[-2]]
        current_level[path[-2]] = new_level

    return new_dict
```

Comment: Thanks for solving the problem. The only point I have to change was, that `k.isnumeric` in line 10 is not applicable to string if its not unicode.

So I changed this line to
`try:
                int(k)
                to_convert.add(tuple(path_stack))
            except:
                pass`

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

You may iterate over your original dict to recursively add `keys` and add value to the final item as:

```
new_dict = {}
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    k_list = key.split('.')
    temp_dict = new_dict
    for k in k_list[:-1]:
        if k not in temp_dict:
            temp_dict[k] = {}
        temp_dict = temp_dict[k]
    temp_dict[k_list[-1]] = value
```

where `my_dict` is your original dict object as mentioned in question.

Final value hold by `new_dict` will be:

```
{
   "Device":{
      "GatewayInfo":{
         "SerialNumber":"A223142D1CC7",
         "ProductClass":"OEM-TX23"
      },
      "DeviceInfo":{
         "SoftwareVersion":"ote-2.2.1"
      },
      "HomePlug":{
         "Interface":{
            "1":{
               "AssociatedDevice":{
                  "1":{
                     "RxPhyRate":522,
                     "Active":1,
                     "TxPhyRate":706,
                     "MACAddress":"af:49:79:e4:64:fc"
                  },
                  "2":{
                     "Active":1,
                     "MACAddress":"af:49:79:e4:64:dd",
                     "RxPhyRate":544,
                     "TxPhyRate":0
                  }
               }
            },
            "2":{
               "AssociatedDevice":{
                  "1":{
                     "RxPhyRate":671,
                     "Active":1,
                     "TxPhyRate":607,
                     "MACAddress":"bf:49:79:e4:64:fc"
                  },
                  "2":{
                     "RxPhyRate":340,
                     "MACAddress":"bf:49:79:e4:64:dd",
                     "TxPhyRate":0,
                     "Active":1
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "Ethernet":{
         "Interface":{
            "1":{
               "MaxBitRate":1000
            },
            "2":{
               "MaxBitRate":1000
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but mentioned in my question. How about the integer values. These integer values should not be in the final dict, insted these should be an indication for the start of an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dive into the python you may be interested in module [dotteddict](https://github.com/zeroxoneb/dotteddict/blob/master/dotteddict/__init__.py).

It's a little tricky but very intersting "pythonic" code. At a moment it doesn't convert numeric keys into list but some concepts from it is definitely worth a time to spend.